# iOS MapKit label building on park map

Tags: iphone, ios4, mapkit

What I'm trying to achieve is that there is an event being held at Exhibition Park in Canberra (that's in Australia) which makes use of the building on the property. What I'm not sure about is how to show these buildings and label them in MapKit when they don't appear in the maps application.

Does anyone have any solutions about this? Should I just use pin points and annotations or is there a better way of accomplishing things?

Please note that I'm unfamiliar with MapKit so as much detail in the answer would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use `MKPinAnnotation` to add pins to the map, configured to show callouts when you tap on them.

The easiest way to pickup MapKit is to watch the WWDC video on the subject, which you can download from the iOS developer portal.